# Creating an independent copy of the entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm creating a new list. I write objects to the new list from the list of entities. Then I will clean items from the list of entities appropriately, which also results in the removal of objects from this new list.

```
final ContributionEntity contributionEntity = this.findContribution(contributionId, DataStatus.WAITING, user, MovieField.PHOTO);

final Set<Long> idsToAddBeforeCleanUp = contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd();

this.cleanUpIdsToAdd(contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd(), contribution.getIdsToAdd(), contributionEntity.getMovie().getPhotos());

private void cleanUpIdsToAdd(final Set<Long> idsToAddFromEntity, final Set<Long> idsToAddFromDto,
                                 final List<? extends MovieInfoEntity> entities) {
        for (final Iterator<Long> it = idsToAddFromEntity.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            final Long id = it.next();
            if (!idsToAddFromDto.contains(id)) {
                it.remove();
                this.delete(entities, id);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code removes the entity from the list of subject photos `contributionEntity` , but also removes objects from the list `idsToAddBeforeCleanUp`.

How do I copy a list from an entity and make it independent of this entity? I do not want to delete items from the list `idsToAddBeforeCleanUp`.

Comment: Almost all Set and List implementations have a copy constructor that will create a (shallow) copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Set<Long> idsToAddBeforeCleanUp = new HashSet<>();   
contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd().foreach(item -> idsToAddBeforeCleanUp.add(item));
```

You didn't really create a new set, you just made another reference to the set. With the code above you make a new list and should it work.